# Cryptographic failure error and metadata file for dll error

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have purchase one software from another company with source code. But when i build it, following two errors had occurring. I researched lot on it. But cant find solution. Generally `.snk` files are for DLLs (to add it in GAC global assembly cache) i can't found `PublicPrivateKeyFile.snk` in app folder or anywhere. Application references number of dlls,so same error is shown for every DLL. What should i do to resolve this errors.

```
Error Cryptographic failure while signing assembly ...\obj\Debug\xyz.dll' -- 'Error reading key file 'c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewCode\abc\Libs\PublicPrivateKeyFile.snk' -- The system cannot find the file specified.` 

Error metadata file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewCode\abc\bin\Debug\xyz.dll' could not be found
```

What is metadata file?
How to resolve both errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Without their `.snk` (strong name key file) you cannot sign as them. Look inside of the `AssemblyInfo.cs` class for the directive `[assembly: ReferenceKeyFile]` and comment that out to remove the signature. You will then be able to use it locally.

A second option is to make your own signature for the `.dll`. Then go through the various ways of making sure that all references to that public key are the same and also figuring out what that key is.

Comment: so if i am creating my own .snk file..then each assembly have its own .snk file or it will common for other dlls.Beacause in their app,they having multiple sub projects and each project is referencing same file PublicPrivateKeyFile.snk